# Modify iframe content after load using php in current page

Tags: php, iframe

The situation is this : My PHP page has an iframe that is displayed ONLY if the user's browser does not support/enable client side scripting, Javascript, etc. (i.e. the iframe is enclosed in noscript tags).

Also, the HTML content of the iframe is loaded from an external source, and the elements come un-styled.

I would like to insert an Inline Style Sheet, in the head section of the iframe document, after the iframe loads, without using client-side scripting, but instead with php placed at some point after the iframe within the current page.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language, which means after the page has loaded in the browser all of the php code has finished executing so there is no way you can modify the `iframe` using php after page load.  You could make the iframe in question link to a new php script and in that script get the html from the external source, modify it's head, then output the modified html

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the page while it's being parsed on the server?

Comment: Yes, like i said, you could make the `iframe` link to a new php page that you create that will get the html from the external source (using `curl` or the method `file_get_contents`), modify that html, then output it.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked very well. I did as you suggested, and used another php script as a form of 'proxy'. All the HTML arrived, editable and all. There was one minor problem though, an image that is a part of the HTML does not show up. Any ideas as to why? Thanks again.

Comment: It's probably because the `img` tag `src` attribute is using a relative path to the image.  You'll have to change the `src` attribute so that it looks like this `http://www.example.com/path/to/img`

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks again.